# Loading mix dependencies marked as test only when the MIX_ENV was not originally set to "test"

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I wish to programmatically run the `mix test` task within my Elixir application. This can be done with `Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1`, though attempting to do so without first setting the `MIX_ENV` environmental variable results in the task refusing to run.

We can set the env with `System.put_env/2`, but then the application will crash once it finds a reference to a module defined in a dependancy marked as test only.

How can I load these dependancies in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We can set the env with System.put_env/2, but then the application will crash once it finds a reference to a module defined in a dependancy marked as test only.

That's on purpose. You need to set the environment variable before Mix is started, otherwise Mix will load the wrong dependencies.

If you are creating a new task, you can tell Mix what is the preferred environment to run it by setting `[preferred_cli_env: [my_task: :test]]` in your project function. Other than that, you have no option besides setting MIX_ENV explicitly.

Comment: Is it not possible to reload the deps once the env has been changed?

Comment: You definitely could. But what about code that was already loaded? Applications that have possibly been started? I would prefer my environments to be "clean" than have a mixture of dev and test code. Some frameworks do what you have mentioned but it just causes pain in the long term.